# Helm - Configmap - Replace only the contents of file and not File Names

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have defined application.properties files in a config dir. Config dir is on the below structure.

```
config
  application.properties
  application-test.properties
  application-dev.properties
  application-prod.properties
```

I have created a helm chart to create the configmap. Helm chart is defined as below

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: nginx-configmap
data:
  {{- (.Files.Glob "config/*").AsConfig | nindent 2 }}
```

I see that the configmap is created.

We are consuming the ConfigMap via environment variables in a running container using the `envFrom` property. (This in my deployment yaml file)

```
spec:
   containers:
   - envFrom:
     - configMapRef:
         name: nginx-configmap
```

I see that the values are stored as environment variables. However the variables are in lower cases.

```
server.port=8080
server.name=localhost
```

Since these are env variables, they have to be uppercase and . should be replaced with _. So, I have modifed my chart as below

```
data:
  {{- (.Files.Glob "config/*").AsConfig | nindent 2 | upper | replace "." "_" }}
```

The generated configmap is as below

```
  APPLICATION_PROPERTIES: |
    SERVER_PORT = 8080
    SERVER_NAME = LOCALHOST
```

Below is the env variables inside container

```
APPLICATION_PROPERTIES=SERVER_PORT = 8080
SERVER_NAME = LOCALHOST
```

My requirement is that only the contents of the file should be upper case and . should be replaced with _.  The filename should not be converted. The filename should be as is.

Can this be achieved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: nginx-configmap
data:
  {{ $root := . }}
  {{ range $path, $bytes := .Files.Glob "config/*" }}
  {{ base $path }}: '{{ $root.Files.Get $path | nindent 2 | upper | replace "." "_"  }}'
  {{ end }}
```

Comment: while adding, I see the configmap are set as

application.properties: ' SERVER_PORT = 8080 SERVER_NAME = LOCALHOST SERVER_GREETING
    = GREETING-SERVICE '

Inside the docker container, I see that 

application.properties= SERVER_PORT = 8080 SERVER_NAME = LOCALHOST SERVER_GREETING = GREETING-SERVICE

echo $SERVER_PORT

echo $application.properties
.properties

This value set is incorrect.

Comment: Can you explain little more. I didn't get it from your comment.

Comment: In configmap, I have added as below

`data:
  {{ range $path, $bytes := .Files.Glob "config/*" }}
  {{ base $path }}: '{{ $.Files.Get $path | nindent 2 | upper | replace "." "_"  }}'
  {{ end }}`

`kubectl describe cm
Data
====
application.properties:
----
 SERVER_PORT = 8080 SERVER_NAME = LOCALHOST SERVER_GREETING = GREETING-SERVICE`

Here all the key value pair are taken as string instead of configmap.

Wanted to pass parameter AsConfig mentioned below
`{{- (.Files.Glob "foo/*").AsConfig | nindent 2 }}`

Comment: Inside the container, env is set as below
`application.properties= SERVER_PORT = 8080 SERVER_NAME = LOCALHOST SERVER_GREETING = GREETING-SERVICE`

`echo  $SERVER_PORT`, when I print the value, its null.

Comment: Replace `=` with `:` in the same way you replaced `.` with `_`.